# Erro ao passar SqlParameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net

Tenho um método pra retornar uma *query*, mas está dando erro.

#### Classe Dados.cs:

```
public static SqlDataReader retornaQuery(SqlCommand query, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                //Instância o sqlcommand com a query sql que será executada e a conexão.
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query.CommandText, connection());

                if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    comando.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                }
                //Executa a query sql.
                var retornaQuery = comando.ExecuteReader(); //Procedure or function 'SP_AUTENTICAR_USUARIOS' expects parameter '@USUARIO', which was not supplied.
                //Fecha a conexão.
                connection().Close();
                //Retorna o dataReader com o resultado
                return retornaQuery;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

#### Classe UsuarioDAO.cs

```
        #region Parâmetros
         private const String PARAM_USU_ID = "ID";
         private const String PARAM_USU_USUARIO = "USUARIO";
         private const String PARAM_USU_SENHA = "SENHA";
        #endregion
        #region Procedures
         private const String PROCEDURE_SP_LISTAR_USUARIOS = "SP_LISTAR_USUARIOS";
         private const String PROCEDURE_SP_AUTENTICAR_USUARIOS = "SP_AUTENTICAR_USUARIOS";
        #endregion

public Boolean Autenticar(Usuario usuario)
        {
            try
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand();
                var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = PROCEDURE_SP_AUTENTICAR_USUARIOS;
                parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = PARAM_USU_SENHA, Value = usuario.UsuSenha, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar});
                parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = PARAM_USU_USUARIO, Value = usuario.UsuUsuario, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });
                using (IDataReader idr = Dados.retornaQuery(cmd, parameters))
                {
                    while (idr.Read())
                    {
                        if (idr["MSG"].Equals("1"))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

> Erro: Procedure or function 'SP_AUTENTICAR_USUARIOS' expects parameter '@USUARIO', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta repassar a informação do commandType dentro do método `retornaQuery`

```
comando.CommandType = query.CommandType;
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara, esse seu erro é porque vocÊ não pode passar uma coleção de SqlParameter no método Add do SqlCommand.

Você poderia mudar e colocar um foreach do tipo:

```
            if (query.Parameters.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (var item in query.Parameters)
                {
                    query.Parameters.Add(item);
                }

            }
```

Mas vai dar outro erro para você. Pois os parametros nãp podem pertencer a outro SqlCommand, para fazer o método do jeito que você precisa, sugeria que você fizesse de outra forma, tipo assim:

```
public static SqlDataReader retornaQuery(String query, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
    {

        try
        {
            //Instância o sqlcommand com a query sql que será executada e a conexão.
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, connection());

            if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
            {
                comando.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
            }


            //Executa a query sql.
            var retornaQuery = comando.ExecuteReader();

            //Fecha a conexão.
            connection().Close();

            //Retorna o dataReader com o resultado
            return retornaQuery;

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Para usar você poderia fazer mais ou menos assim:

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "ID"});
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "Descricao" });

        Question28302.retornaQuery("query", parameters);
```

Espero que ajude.

---

Cara, faltou adicionar o @ nas strings de parametro, faz assim:

```
     private const String PARAM_USU_ID = "@ID";
     private const String PARAM_USU_USUARIO = "@USUARIO";
     private const String PARAM_USU_SENHA = "@SENHA";
```

Comment: Como passo o valor do parâmetro?

Comment: Onde tem a linha:  parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "ID"});

Coloca uma virgula , tem uma propriedade Value, ai você coloca o valor.

Comment: Ok; mas tá dando outro erro: `Procedure or function 'SP_AUTENTICAR_USUARIOS' expects parameter '@USUARIO', which was not supplied.`; Sendo que estou passando o parâmetro. Vou atualizar minha pergunta para você ver

Comment: Pergunta atualizada!

Comment: Tava faltando o command type kkk

Answer (score 1):

Cara que código estranho esse seu.

Nessa linha vc deve passar um valor de uma dictonary

```
comando.Parameters.Add(query.Parameters.);
```

Por exemplo tenho uma query assim.

```
Select * from Produtos where IDProduto = @IDProduto
```

Nessa sua linha

```
comando.Parameters.Add(query.Parameters.);
```

vc tem que colocar assim uma dictonary

```
 parametros.add(@IDProduto, IDProduto);


foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> parametro in parametros)
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametro.Key, parametro.Value);
}
```

se não entender posso colocar um outro código.